# What was the Chant Emiya Shirou used to Enter the Reality Marble World?

Tags: fate-stay-night

In Fate/Stay night: Unlimited Blade Works 2nd Season Episode 12, What was the original Chant Shirou used to  enter the Reality Marble World? I **think** there were some normal dialogues between his original Chant which had me confused so can anyone who can clear this mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

actually the one posted by [RNGesus.exe](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/57752/1587) is the wrong one. while i have not seen the ufotable series, looking at [the wikia on it](https://typemoon.fandom.com/wiki/Unlimited_Blade_Works#Variations) you see it's [Heroic Spirit EMIYA's chant](https://typemoon.fandom.com/wiki/Unlimited_Blade_Works#Archer) as it's the one that ends with him saying *"So as I pray"*.

since the question asks for Emiya Shirou, [his is](https://typemoon.fandom.com/wiki/Unlimited_Blade_Works#Shirou)

```
 I am the bone of my sword.
 Steel is my body and fire is my blood.
 I have created over a thousand blades.
 Unaware of loss,
 Nor aware of gain.
 Withstood pain to create weapons, waiting for one’s arrival.
 I have no regrets. This is the only path.
 My whole life was Unlimited Blade Works.
```

the wikia links above also show there are different chants for EMIYA depending on the dub (Bang Zoom and Animax) and a different from for Shirou in *PRISMA☆ILLYA* (there is also a link to EMIYA Alter's version from *Fate Grand/Order*)

Answer (score -1):

This is the chant

```
I am the bone of my sword
Steel is my body and fire is my blood
I have created over a thousand blades
Unknown to Death
Nor known to Life
Have withstood pain to create many weapons
Yet,those hands will never hold anything
So as i pray,Unlimited Blade Works
```

and no there was dialogue when he was chanting .

Comment: That's the chant recited in an earlier episode by Archer which differs from the one Emiya Shirou used in the episode OP mentioned.